# Is there another way to copy hundreds of files during build other than with a post-build step or using Copy to Output Directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# DLL project containing hundreds resources that have to be copied in place for the EXE project to see them.  These resources cannot be embedded in the DLL.

I know how to create a post-build step to copy the files.

```
MKDIR $(TargetDir)\Special
XCOPY /S /E /Y /C $(ProjectDir)\Special $(TargetDir)\Special
```

The problem is that this post-build step only copies the files to the output directory of the DLL.  It does not copy the output to the directory of the EXE.  I need all of this in the output directory of the EXE.  Furthermore, there are actually two EXE projects in the solution and there could be more.

I seem to recall that there is a way to tell MSBuild (or Visual Studio) that these hundreds of files are to be copied to the final output directory of whatever is referencing the DLL.

There is also the property called "Copy to Output Directory" which appears to work.  The trouble is that there are hundred of files, several people work on this, and if someone messes up just one file, the system will break.  Discovering that a single file out of hundreds had this little property flipped the wrong way is going to be troublesome.

**UPDATE**

I tried the ideas mentioned below and found a few things...

**Idea 1 (@GuyVdN)**

Put this in the Project somewhere

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySpecialFiles Include="Special\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And then just above the closing `</Project>` tag:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)\Special" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)\Special')" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySpecialFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(MySpecialFiles->'$(OutputPath)\Special\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

**Idea 2 (@user704808)**

Put this in the Project somewhere

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySpecialFiles Include="Special\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And then just above the closing `</Project>` tag:

```
  <Target Name="SetCopyToOutputDirectoryOnResourceItems" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </EmbeddedResource>
      <MySpecialFiles Condition="'%(MySpecialFiles.Extension)'=='.py'">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </MySpecialFiles >
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

**Problems**

- Neither one copies the Special\ folder to the EXE's output directory.
- Idea 1 outputs Special\ to the DLL's output directory only
- Idea 2 did not output anything at all. :-(

**Update 2**

@Jimmy's idea worked almost perfect.  A clean build didn't remove the files.

Comment: Please see my comment below regarding "Idea 2".

Answer (score 1):

If the 'Copy To Output Directory' setting will work, you can put something like this into your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="StuffToCopy\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This will pick up every file under StuffToCopy (recursively) and copy it to the output directory.  The only issue I've run into using this approach is that sometimes VS will expand the ItemGroup to every file under the directory, so keep an eye on your source control changes, and you should be fine.

Comment: This is almost working. A Clean build doesn't remove the files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to use the post-build step of each exe project instead of the dll project. That way the `$(TargetDir)` should be correct. For the source directory you can use the `$(SolutionDir)` and append the folder name of your resources to it.

Another option would be to create your own MSBuild script ([Walkthrough: Creating an MSBuild Project File from Scratch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx)), that way you can use the more powerful [Copy task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx).

Comment: The Copy task throws this message, but despite this, I think this is close ` The Copy task does not support copying directories.`

Comment: The last example on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) shows you how to copy a directory recursively, including all files and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Trade the post-build command-line script for approach that ensures that all items in the DLL projects representing the resources your EXE needs have the value `PreserveNewest` for the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata attribute. Copy the following to the end of each of the DLL .csproj files, just above `</Project>`. Adjust/add/remove the example condition and item types (`EmbeddedResource` and `SomeOtherItemType`).

```
<Target Name="SetCopyToOutputDirectoryOnResourceItems" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </EmbeddedResource>
      <SomeOtherItemType Condition="'%(SomeOtherItemType.Extension)'=='.someextension'>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </SomeOtherItemType>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Since this ItemGroup is in a Target and does not add new items, it will not cause Visual Studio to make the project changes @Jimmy described in his answer.

Comment: See update above -- this didn't seem to output anything at all.

Comment: So the idea was not to add `<ItemGroup><MySpecialFiles Include="Special\**\*" /></ItemGroup>` at all, but only my code block.  Substitute `.py` for `.someextension`, and `None` for `SomeOtherItemType`. That assumes the existing .py items in your .csproj look like `<None Include="....py" />`. If it isn't `None` then use whatever item type it is (perhaps `Content`?).